# Binding not working as expected when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a button that's supplied with data and this is used to unfollow or follow a user.  What should happen is that I press the button, it changes the `isFollowing` property on the user, and then the text updates from `unfollow` to `follow`. However, this doesn't work. Here's my code that can be put into a playground (simplified for the purposes of this just to show the core elements):

```
struct User: Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var isFollowing: Bool
}

final class MyModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var users: [User] = [User(isFollowing: true)]

  func unfollow(_ user: Binding<User>) async throws {
    user.wrappedValue.isFollowing = false
  }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel

  var body: some View {
    UserListView(users: $model.users)
  }
}

final class PagedUsers: ObservableObject {
  @Published var loadedUsers: [Binding<User>] = []
  @Binding var totalUsers: [User]

  init(totalUsers: Binding<[User]>) {
    self._totalUsers = totalUsers
    let firstUser = $totalUsers.first!
    loadedUsers.append(firstUser)
  }
}

struct UserListView: View {
  @StateObject private var pagedUsers: PagedUsers

  init(users: Binding<[User]>) {
    self._pagedUsers = StateObject(wrappedValue: PagedUsers(totalUsers: users))
  }

  var body: some View {
    ForEach(pagedUsers.loadedUsers) { user in
      MyView(user: user)
    }
  }
}


struct MyView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel
  @Binding var user: User

  var body: some View {
    
    Button(
      action: {
        Task {
          do {
            try await model.unfollow($user)
          } catch {
            print("Error!", error)
          }
        }
      },
      label: {
        Text(user.isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow")
      }
    )
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
  ContainerView()
    .environmentObject(MyModel())
)
```

I think it's not working because of something to do with the passing of bindings, but I can't quite work out why. Possibly it's the setup of `PagedUsers`? However, this needs to be there because in my app code I essentially pass all the user data to it, and return "pages" of users from this, which gets added to as the user scrolls.

Comment: Binding only works inside of a struct that is View reliably because of its inheritance of DynamicProperty. The only wrapper that works in a class is Published and it only works if the class is an ObservableObject

Comment: @loremipsum Right but I should be able to pass Bindings around and have them update the view shouldn't I? Still unclear where it's going wrong in my code

Comment: No Binding is by definition a two way connection that gets its updated value from the View when reloading. When you pass it to a class,that updated value is spotty. You might find a way to get it to work sometimes but it is not reliable. Remove all the Binding references from all you classes. The dilema of how to connect a list/object from a parent ObservableObject to a child ObservableObject gets asked all the time. How to work around that issue is resolved in many ways but the simplest is to dismiss the idea that the list will exist in the child ObservableObject, keep the Binding in the View

Comment: Removing the bindings results in 1. Being unable to mutate the User value, 2. Data being duplicated as they're passed by value not reference, 3. No refreshes of the View. Happy to be proved wrong with altered sample code though.

Comment: Lol, show your new code and where u get the error

Comment: The only issue I see that would cause it would be `loadedUsers` You would have to compensate somehow like instead of saving the user save the `id`

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you need *two* classes for **users** ... why not put them in one in different @Published vars?

IMHO then you don't need any bindings at all!
Here is a working code with only one class, hopefully you can build from this:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct AppMain: App {
    
    @StateObject private var model = MyModel()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContainerView()
                .environmentObject(model)
        }
    }
}


struct User: Hashable, Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var isFollowing: Bool
}

class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var users: [User] = [User(isFollowing: true), User(isFollowing: true), User(isFollowing: true)]
    
    func unfollow(_ user: User) async throws {
        if let index = users.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == user.id}) {
            self.objectWillChange.send()
            users[index].isFollowing = false
        }
    }
}


struct ContainerView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel
    
    var body: some View {
        UserListView(users: model.users)
    }
}


struct UserListView: View {
    
    let users: [User]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(users) { user in
                MyView(user: user)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: MyModel
    var user: User
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(
            action: {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await model.unfollow(user)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error!", error)
                    }
                }
            },
            label: {
                Text(user.isFollowing ? "Unfollow" : "Follow")
            }
        )
    }
}
```